# Is it possible to override a generisized function?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Is it possible to override a generisized  function as illustrated in the code snippet below?

```
interface A {
}

interface B extends A {
}


abstract class C {
    protected abstract <T extends A> void abc(T xyz);
}

class D extends C {
    @Override
protected void abc(B xyz) {
    // doesn't compile
    // The method abc(B) of type D must override or implement a supertype method
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You mean a *generic* function? I'm not sold on this 'generisized' fad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your code, an instance of `D` is an instance of `C`, and consequently must accept *any* subclass of A as an argument to its `abc()` method. What you want is an instance which only accepts a specific subclass. You need to generify `C` (rather than just `C#abc()`). Then you can make `D` extend `C<B>`, like so:

```
interface A {
}

interface B extends A {
}

abstract class C<T extends A> {
    protected abstract void abc(T xyz);
}

class D extends C<B> {
    @Override
    protected void abc(B xyz) {
        // Compiles
    }
}
```

A proof that you can't generify the method only:

```
interface A {
}

interface B extends A {
    public void def();
}

abstract class C {
    protected abstract <T extends A> void abc(T xyz);
}

class D extends C {
    @Override
    protected void abc(B xyz) {
        xyz.def();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        D d = new D();
        d.abc(new B(){}); // Invokes def() on a B, OK
        C c = (C) d;      // Cast to a C, OK
        c.abc(new A(){}); // C#abc() applies to an A, but tries to invoke
                          // a's def(), which it lacks
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, Thanks. But what if you really only wanted to to generify C#abc, rather than C?

Comment: I've edited the original answer to add some code demonstrating why you can't generify the method.

Answer (score -1):

Your class `D` should extend `C<B>`.

Comment: That won't work, as it's the function abc that's generic not the class C.